# Concatenate mulitple columns to a new column conditionally in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with below structure and I need to check columns, field1 to field5 based on certain conditions and generate a new column,EvaulatedReasons like below

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  ("C002", Some(1),Some("edf"),Some(10),Some(200),Some(500)),
  ("C001", Some(2), None,None, None,None) , //null case
  ("C003", Some(1),Some("abc"),Some(80),Some(200),Some(900))   
    
).toDF("CustomerId", "Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5")

df.show(10,false)
```

Expected output:
[image]

In sql, I could do something like case statements and generate the EvaluatedReasons column but in Scala is there any optimal way other than using WHEN statements?
Note : My dataframe has 8 columns to check like this and for simplicity sample dataframe has 5 columnns.
I have working version but its not elegant

```
   val resultDf = (df
  .withColumn("Field1Reason", when(col("Field1") =!= "1", lit("xyx, ")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field2Reason", when(col("Field2").isNull, lit("Field2 Is empty, ")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field3Reason", when(col("Field3").isNull, lit("Field3 Is empty, ")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field4Reason", when(col("Field4").isNull, lit("Field4 Is empty, ")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field5Reason", when(col("Field5").isNull, lit("Field5 Is empty, ")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field2NotNullReason", when(col("Field2").isNotNull && col("Field2") =!= "abc", 
                                           lit("Field2 not equal to abc,")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field3NotNullReason", when(col("Field3").isNotNull && col("Field3") < 10, lit("Field3 < 10, ")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field4NotNullReason", when(col("Field4").isNotNull && col("Field4") < 100, lit("Field4 < 100, ")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("Field5NotNullReason", when(col("Field5").isNotNull && col("Field5") < 800, lit("Field5 < 800,")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .withColumn("EvaluatedReasons",
    concat(
      col("Field1Reason"), col("Field2Reason"), col("Field3Reason"),
      col("Field4Reason"), col("Field5Reason"), col("Field2NotNullReason"),
      col("Field3NotNullReason"), col("Field4NotNullReason"), col("Field5NotNullReason")
    )
              
  ).drop("Field1Reason", "Field2Reason", "Field3Reason", "Field4Reason", "Field5Reason",
        "Field2NotNullReason", "Field3NotNullReason", "Field4NotNullReason", "Field5NotNullReason")
               )
```

Comment: Commenting as it's not directly answering your question, but this has a very DQ feel to it and if you intend to store the resulting EvaluatedReasons as strings I'd recommend you not, it's wasteful, doesn't allow easy auditing and doesn't allow easy evolution of your check message.  If any of that sounds worthwhile it could be useful to look at [Quality Rules](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/getting_started/a_first_rulesuite/), if for no other reason that to borrow ideas - the background for Quality is [here](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/background/about/).

Comment: Thanks Chris, i just added some dummy data  for example but actual functionality is useful like it gives the reasons about certain data and later we surface this in the UI . Its not related to Data quality

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** - Check below code.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

scala> df.show(false)
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|CustomerId|Field1|Field2|Field3|Field4|Field5|
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|C002      |1     |edf   |10    |200   |500   |
|C001      |2     |null  |null  |null  |null  |
|C003      |1     |edf   |80    |200   |900   |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

```
scala> val columns = df.columns.filter(_.toLowerCase.contains("field"))
columns: Array[String] = Array(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5)
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

// Defined case class to hold all conditions for all columns.

case class Condition( columns: Seq[String], statements: Seq[String], matched: String, notMatched: String = "") {  
  def contains(column: String) = columns.contains(column.toLowerCase)
  def ==(column: String): Column =
    when(
      expr(statements.map(f => s"${column} ${f}").reduce(_ + " AND " + _)),
      lit(s"${column} ${matched}")
    ).otherwise(lit(notMatched))
}

// Added all required conditions.

val conditions = Seq(
    Condition(Seq("field1"), Seq("!= 1"),  "xyx"),
    Condition(Seq("field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"), Seq("is null"), "is empty"),
    Condition(Seq("field2"), Seq("is not null", " != 'abc'"), "is not equal to abc"),
    Condition(Seq("field3"), Seq("is not null", " < 10"), "< 10"),
    Condition(Seq("field4"), Seq("is not null", " < 100"), "< 100"),
    Condition(Seq("field5"), Seq("is not null", " < 800"), "< 800"),
)
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val reasonsExpr = concat_ws(
    ", ", 
    filter(
        array(columns.map{ c => conditions.filter(_.contains(c)).map(_ == c)}.flatten:_*), 
        c => trim(c) =!= ""
       )
   ).as("EvaluatedReasons")
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

```
scala> df.select($"*", reasonsExpr).show(false)

+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CustomerId|Field1|Field2|Field3|Field4|Field5|EvaluatedReasons                                                              |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|C002      |1     |edf   |10    |200   |500   |Field2 is not equal to abc, Field5 < 800                                      |
|C001      |2     |null  |null  |null  |null  |Field1 xyx, Field2 is empty, Field3 is empty, Field4 is empty, Field5 is empty|
|C003      |1     |abc   |80    |200   |900   |                                                                              |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: it's not giving  the expected output. for eg. for the customerId , C003, EvaulatedReasons should be null as field1 to field5 does not satisfy the rules (see the sql case statement above).  Similarily for C002 the evaulatedReasons should be "Field2 is not equal to abc, Field5 < 800"  as  field2 and field5 failed the conditions . For C001, it should be "Field2 is empty,Field3 is empty,Field4 is empty,field5 is empty". See the  "Expected output: mentioned in the question pls

Comment: You can check now, I have updated.

Comment: Its giving compile error, not found: value filter
           filter(
           ^. Also can you pls add few comments to explain

Answer (score 0):

Validations can be stored in collection, and applied to DataFrame with foldLeft:

```
val validations = Seq(
  (col("Field1") =!= "1", "xyx"),
  (col("Field2").isNull, "Field2 Is empty"),
  (col("Field3").isNull, "Field3 Is empty"),
  (col("Field4").isNull, "Field4 Is empty"),
  (col("Field5").isNull, "Field5 Is empty")
)
val columnNames = validations.map(_._2)

val result = validations
  .foldLeft(df) { case (df, (validation, message)) => df.withColumn(message, when(validation, message).otherwise(null)) }
  .withColumn("EvaluatedReasons", concat_ws(",", columnNames.map(col): _*))
  .drop(columnNames: _*)
```

Result is:

```
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CustomerId|Field1|Field2|Field3|Field4|Field5|EvaluatedReasons                                                       |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|C002      |1     |edf   |10    |200   |500   |                                                                       |
|C001      |2     |null  |null  |null  |null  |xyx, Field2 Is empty, Field3 Is empty, Field4 Is empty, Field5 Is empty|
|C003      |1     |abc   |80    |200   |900   |                                                                       |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```